# Heavy processes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ram

I have some databases in a server. This server has 16GB RAM, and this system just use as database server.

After a while of working with different databases I see that most of RAM space (about 14GB) is used and if I use other applications and work again, I can't use my computer and it is hanging up.

How can I find out which database has more usage of RAM and after that, how can I find out which query make this resources full?

Comment: That is normal behavior for SQL Server - unless you restrict it, SQL Server will use up all the memory available on a server - to speed up its processing. That's **not** any indication of an error or a problem - not at all - it's SQL Server doing its best to perform well!

Comment: But it would be interested to know the real RAM use of sql server. The task manager don't really show the real use of RAM sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Profiler is a nifty tool for analyzing which queries that comes to the databases.

```
set statistics time on
```

and

```
set statistics io on
```

and

```
set statistics profile on
```

Statistics is a great way of analyzing a specific query when you've found one you think is slow..

Do you have no idea which queries that are the heaviest? You should really go through your code and see what kind of for loops, subqueries or other monsterous queries you have running and go from what you believe is heavy. And test these in Sql Server Management...

Comment: I'm just managing system and I don't know about the written Codes. so I try to use sql profiler but there is no clear answer in commands. After awhile RAM is full and can't empty without restart!

Comment: How many databases are you running on the server? and for which applications? What kind of applications, and how heavy are their uses?

Comment: about 10 Databases. The Applications are different. Web based, Win bases and about 400users using it.

Answer (score 1):

There's some useful information in the sys.dm_exec_query_stats table (2005 onwards) to find which queries being run are most intensive in terms of IO, elapsed time etc.

Try running this for example (to see details on the last 25 queries run):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 t.TEXT AS query, s.*
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) t
ORDER  BY s.last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: In title I wrote SQL2008, I think this Query can help. I need to check it.

Comment: @HamedR, you're correct - I hadn't noticed. Apologies - I've edited my answer.